# Is the i18n goal in Maven required for GWT internationalization?

Tags: gwt, maven, internationalization

I am working on a project using GWT and Maven that I am including internationalization in.  It seems to me that it takes longer to build and run the i18n generated files than it does to add new strings into my Constants interface manually.
My question is:  Is it required that I include the i18n goal in the POM?  Or is it just a tool intended to make it easier to create a Constants interface from a pre-existing properties file?  I am new to Maven and believe the goal is just a tool, but am unable to confirm based on my research that it is not needed.  Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, not required - as you say, it is just there to make it easier. The same is true of the `gwt:generateAsync` goal, which builds the Async RPC interfaces for you, based on the `RemoteService` subtypes you've already defined.

I don't use either one - I prefer to build my own, and document where needed (or not). My poms include just a `gwt:test` for any unit tests I've devised, and a `gwt:compile` to actually compile to JavaScript.

Keep in mind that a significant percentage of GWT developers do not use Maven, and Constants/Messages and RPC still works just fine for them without these goals.

Comment: Thanks, I was pretty sure that was how it worked, but wanted to double check.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me, you should **not** use the `i18n` goal in your POM. It should only be used once in a while to synchronize your code (interface) with a properties file. On a day-to-day basis, you should rather work with your interfaces for the *canonical* locale and manually update the properties files for the translations.

There are way too much things you can do with a `Constants` or `Messages` interface that cannot be inferred *from* a properties file: non-string constants, plurals in messages, etc.